# Android Studio SiliCompressor: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, firebase, video, firebase-storage

I want to upload videos to Firebase Storage and compress them. For that i'm trying to use Silicompressor.

This is the onClick for the upload button:

```
postVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new CompressVideo(getActivity()).execute(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), videoUri), 
                    storageReference.toString());
            }
        });
```

videoUri is the uri i'm getting from the onActivityResult method and storageReference is the path to the video in Firebase Storage.

This is the doInBackground() method in AsyncTask class:

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... paths) {
            String filePath = null;
            String path = paths[0];
            String directoryPath = paths[1];
            try {
                filePath = SiliCompressor.with(mContext).compressVideo(path, directoryPath);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return filePath;
        }
```

I'm getting this error: `An error occurred while executing doInBackground()` pointing me to

`filePath = SiliCompressor.with(mContext).compressVideo(path, directoryPath);`

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. If someone can help me i would be very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, have you found the answer?